# Update Android Emulator in android studio 3.3 Failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I upgrade android studio to 3.3. Emulator version is 28.0.22.

Now, new version 28.0.23 is in repository :

[image]

When I want to update to new version I got error:

```
2019-02-03 16:43:06,975 [hread 1030]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Packages to install:  
2019-02-03 16:43:06,975 [hread 1030]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - Android Emulator (emulator) 
2019-02-03 16:43:06,975 [hread 1030]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - 

2019-02-03 16:43:06,977 [hread 1030]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 28.0.23)". 
2019-02-03 16:43:06,980 [hread 1030]   WARN - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Failed to read or create install properties file. 
2019-02-03 16:43:06,980 [hread 1030]   WARN - ess.util.ProgressIndicatorBase - This progress indicator is indeterminate, this may lead to visual inconsistency. Please call setIndeterminate(false) before you start progress. 
2019-02-03 16:43:06,980 [hread 1030]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 28.0.23)". 
2019-02-03 16:43:06,984 [hread 1030]   WARN - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Failed to read or create install properties file. 
2019-02-03 16:43:06,984 [hread 1030]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Failed packages: 
2019-02-03 16:43:06,985 [hread 1030]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - Android Emulator (emulator)
```

What's going on?

Comment: New Emulator version is 28.0.23 not 28.0.32. And I have successfully updated without any error or issue.

Comment: Ops sorry it is mistake, I mean also is `28.0.32`. I got error and now by command line my problem solved. I changed version in my question .Thanks@PratikButani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally install emulator new version.I think it is android studio gui bug so in installed by command line:

```
sdkmanager "emulator" --proxy=http --proxy_host=127.0.0.1 --proxy_port=8118
```

Now every think is ok.
I hope this, help someone stuck in this situation

Answer (score 2):

The same happened to me. I had to do a full install of the new emulator version rather than updating it.

I don't know the reason of the failure though

Comment: I couldn't uninstall  Emulator from sdk manager so i deleted it from sdk folder. Now i can not install Emulator  from sdk.I got same error.:-( @devnull69

Answer (score 2):

When I got popup that "Android Emulator - Update available", I have just clicked and updated.

Try to **RUN Android studio** as **administrator** and may it will work.

[image]

Hope it will work for you also.

Comment: I have never run android studio with admin privilege.I did not a problem in update package but for emulator in new version i got error. I installed by command for now .Thanks dude